# Angularjs breaking up controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have some very long controllers in angularjs. What are some ways of breaking them up into more organizable sections. The purpose is to get them easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Function.prototype.externalCall = function (varsInContext) {

    var
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {

            for(v in varsInContext) {
                this[v] = varsInContext[v];
            }

            return fToBind.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
}

var externalFunction = function (scope) {

    console.log('hello "' + scope.name + '" ' + '"' + this.scope2.lastName + '"');

    scope.name = 'Hooo ' + scope.name
    this.scope2.lastName = 'Huuu ' + this.scope2.lastName
};

var c = function (scope2) {

    this.f = externalFunction.externalCall(
        {
            scope2: scope2
        }
    );

};

var scope2 = {};
scope2.lastName = 'Descalzo';

var o = new c(scope2);

var scope = {};
scope.name = 'Andres';

o.f(scope);

console.log(scope);
console.log(scope2);
```

for example if you have a controller similar to this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.contact);
        $scope.contact = "";
    };

}]);
```

you can change for this:

```
(function() { 

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

        $scope.add = addContact.externalCall({ $scope: $scope });

    }]);

    function addContact() {

        this.$scope.contacts.push(this.$scope.contact);

        this.$scope.contact = "";
    }

}());
```

Note: the code of extension is based on [bind function in mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you organize your code into re-usable Angular modules.  For example, suppose you've just created a custom modal dialog plug in: ngModal.js. You could organize all the code for this module in one or more files:

```
angular.module('ngModal', ['ngAnimate'])
.directive('ngDir1', function() {
    ...
 })
.directive('ngDir2', function() {
    ...
 })
.controller('ngCtrl1', function() {
    ...
 })
 .config(function() {
    ...
  });
```

The module does one thing (create Modal Dialogs), and in this example, there is one module dependency: ngAnimate.

Whenever you need to use this plugin in another application, all you need to do is reference the dependent script files, and add the 'ngModal' as a dependency.

For example:
    
    
    var myNewApp = angular.module("myNewApp", ["ngModal"]);